# Android view asbolute out of parent

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

My question is does it exist a way to put view out of his parent ?
I'm trying to do this but I don't know how to do it

I tried to use a RelativeLayout and a ConstraintLayout but I still don't work...

```
                    </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/card_promotion_image"
                        android:layout_width="128dp"
                        android:layout_height="110dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="-20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/im_carrying_letters" />
                </RelativeLayout>


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JftS5.png)

[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cviiP.png)

Comment: replace RelativeLayout with FrameLayout

Comment: My god that was that simple... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FrameLayout` helps in stacking views on top of each other so replace `RelativeLayout` in your code with `FrameLayout`

Your XML will be:

```
                </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/card_promotion_image"
                    android:layout_width="128dp"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="-20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/im_carrying_letters" />
            </FrameLayout>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

İf you want to move it horizontally out of its super view, in the code, try modifying **translationX** property. If you want to move it vertically, try modifying the **translationZ** property. And also dont forget to set the super view's **clipToPadding** and **clipChildren** properties to **false** so that the view you move can be displayed out of the borders of its super view